# F-Droid keeps downloading apps that were installed from other stores

Tags: application-autoupdate, f-droid

F-Droid, again and again, downloads updates for an app that is installed via another (namely Play) store.
Obviously, it cannot be installed because of different signatures.

How can I get F-Droid to ignore foreign-store apps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For these common apps-  In F-Droid, open the info page of an app in question, click on the 3-pointed menu and select to ignore all updates for this app.

[image]

[Source](https://f-droid.org/forums/topic/some-apps-are-detected-by-both-play-store-and-f-droid-is-this-ok/)

**Edit:** Thanks to [input from BubullC](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/176708/f-droid-keeps-downloading-of-apps-that-were-installed-from-other-stores/176709?noredirect=1#comment240662_176709) this feature is incorporated in the latest version of F-droid. I haven't verified it but adding it for benefit of future vistors

Comment: this works - thank you! but it would be great if F-Droid would recognize by itself that it is not responsible for these apps

Comment: Maybe suggest that in F-Droid forums, of not done already ? I didn't check

Comment: @vlad_tepesch It does now, since version 1.0 :-)

Comment: @BubuIIC- Thanks for the input. Haven't verified it but will add to the answer with credits to you